# JavaScript: Is there a way to revert or undo .innerHTML.toLowerCase();?

Tags: javascript, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Is there a way to "reverse" changing the innerHTML of an element to lowercase? Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
someText = document.querySelector(".wrapper").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
console.log(someText)
  // Console Log Output: "<p>some text.</p>"
```

Is there then a way to reverse, remove or undo the `toLowerCase();`, in order to return the paragraph text back to its original case? Obviously I can't just change it to UpperCase, as it will change all the text to uppercase instead of original case.

```
someText = document.querySelector(".wrapper").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
console.log(someText);
  // Console Log Output: "<p>some text.</p>"
someText = document.querySelector(".wrapper").innerHTML.toUpperCase();
console.log(someText);
  // Console Log Output: "<p>SOME TEXT.</p>"
```

However, `toLowerCase();` and `toUpperCase;` were the only options I could find, nothing like `toOriginalCase();`. I want the console log to return `<p>Some text.</p>` again after I revert the change.

I am trying to use this method in a search functionality.

Currently on my website, https://www.codeeverydamnday.com/, if you search, for example, "Javascript" from the home page, you'll be brought to a page of search results that do indeed match and highlight the search term, but that is because I have lowercased everything on the page (as you can see in the first post, "day twenty-four", where I have several variations of the word "Javascript", like "javaScript" and "Javascript", that are all showing lowercase).

[image]

That is because I changed the search term to lowercase, then changed all the text on the results page to lowercase before I started matching the search term to its instances on the page and highlighting them. Once matched and highlighted, I would like to revert the text back to its original case and return that to the UI.

Edit: I also tried adding and then removing a `style.textTransform = "lowercase";` , but kept running into issues with that.

Comment: No, you cannot reverse toLowerCase(). Why don't you just store the original string in a temporary variable ?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't store the initial state of a string when you call a function to transform it, you're responsible for it

Comment: If you’re only doing this for visual/presentational purpose, use CSS instead, ie `text-transform: lowercase`. Then you don’t need to manipulate the actual text node.

Comment: not sure why you are using special quote characters, you want to only use `"`, not `“` nor `”`

Comment: @navigator good idea and I thought of that, but in my real-life case I am manipulating the text first (adding some html to highlight some words that match a search term when the text is all lowercase), and then I want to return the original text with the HTML changes I made, so it will not be the original text exactly.

Comment: @terry I think you commented just as I added my update to the end of the question, but I tried text-transform and couldn’t get it to work for some reason! I may play around with it a little more.

Comment: @Trevor Kropp my bad, I added the edit from my phone so that was the default quotation mark character. In my actual code I am of course using the plain text version of the quotation marks.

Comment: Is there an actual need to change anything to lowercase, other than to do a search? You can do a case-insensitive search via [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: the state before calling toLowerCase is lost, you'd need to store it yourself. but if the original capitalization is not random, and it follows a proper english grammar, you could implement a function that capitalizes the first letter of every sentence, although capitalizing names would be harder

Comment: What errors were you getting with `style.textTransform`? I tested it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @kmoser I will read more about .match!

Comment: This example on codepen might help you. https://codepen.io/jamesqquick/pen/XWJxBQv?editors=1010

Comment: @RolandoYera thank you for that example! I think it could indeed help me. I might try using the filter function instead of what I've got set up now.

Comment:    "noice"... Good luck..

Comment: @TrevorKropp so it wasn't an error I was getting, but while textTransform did indeed change the words on the UI to lower case, it didn't change them in the DOM/HTML Elements panel (original case remained). So, in my case, when I tried to match a lowercase search term to all of its instances on the results page, it only matched to the true lowercase words. (Ex. if I searched "javascript" It would only match the word "javascript", not "Javascript" or "JavaScript", for example.

Comment: @TrevorKropp just added a link to my real page near the bottom of my question so you can see what's going on in real life, if that helps.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov not yet, I am doing some research on the .match() function that another user brought up, and also trying to interpret the codepen example that another user brought up to see if I can apply in my case. I'm still new at JS though, so it will take me some time to try all of these suggestions!

Comment: @KatieReynolds, It seems to me that I did not fully understand your task, but I gave the answer. Check and tell me pls, do you need such a result?

Comment: @KatieReynolds remember to upvote any answers that are useful, and accept an answer if it answers your question. It's how SO can surface information for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different answer, because the original post (prior to a fairly heavy edit) didn't mention this was for effecting text highlighting, having fallen in the trap of being a [classic XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (asking about how to undo property assignment when the real problem was how to get to look lowercase).

The *actual* solution here is to not do text replacement at all, but to make sure that the highlighting markup is tied to CSS, not JS, that ensures that no matter what case the text actually is in, it's presented as lowercase to the user, with a highlight background color:

```css
p {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.highlight {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  background: #FFFF0050;
}
```

```html
<p>
  For example, to highlight <span class="highlight">JavaScript</span> in
  this "paragraph" of <span class="highlight">TEXT</span>.
</p>
```

The page text casing never changes, but the *presentation* does. We get "everything in lowercase" entirely for free without needing any `textContent` or `innerHTML` caching, or needing to "undo" anything with respect to the source. CSS only changes the way our source is presented, and the moment we take the highlight class (or outer tags) away, the effect goes away and we see the original text case again.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I’ll try something like this instead! Because I’m dynamically changing which words are highlighted based on a user-input search box, I’ll need to add a couple extra steps to target those words (adding a class to those words in JS and then removing only the text-transform style while leaving the background color style). Will mark this one as the new answer!

Comment: that part at least will be trivial to both toggle, and undo: toggling on the JS side is just `e.classList.toggle(...)` (or add/remove), and turning marked up stretches back into pure text would be something like ```document.querySelectorAll(`span.highlight`).forEach(e => e.outerHTML = e.textContent)```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply store the original HTML on the element.

```js
// nothing stops you from creating your own property on the div#wrapper element
// which you can use to store the original HTML in
wrapper.originalHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Some text.</p>
</div>
<button onclick="wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML.toLowerCase()">toLowerCase()</button>
<button onclick="wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.originalHTML">and back</button>
```

That being said, your whole `toLowerCase()` approach for searching is not what you need to do.

Instead, use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to do [case-insensitive matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags).

See this simple example:

```js
s.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let regex = new RegExp(s.value, 'gi');
  console.log(text.innerText.match(regex));
})
```

```html
<div id="text">foobar <span>FooBAR <i>fooBar</i> Foo</span>Bar foObAR</div>

<input type="search" id="s" placeholder="type &quot;foobar&quot; here">
```

Comment: While I'm still having some trouble replicating on my own code, I think this answer will help me the most, so I have marked it as the answer. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @KatieReynolds Please note that for simplicity purposes, I have referenced the elements directly with their `id` values as a variable name. In any non-demo code, you should always make sure to retrieve these elements from the DOM first by doing the likes of `const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: no, because `innerHTML` (and `textContent`, which you should be using instead for text, *never* use `innerHTML` unless you're actually building HTML, and even then, using the DOM methods is almost always better) are standard object properties on DOM nodes, and if you overwrite a property with a new value, that's its new value. There is nothing to restore, because the only thing that exists is the current value.

Of course, you can certainly reformat the string after the fact (e.g. capitalising every first letter in a sentence) but the original value is lost: this will be a *new* operation, based the *exising* lowercase string.

Comment: Totally, makes sense. As a JS newb I was hoping there was an easy way that I just hadn't heard of yet. >_<

Comment: Nope. Once you assign a new value, the old one's gone.

Comment: There is a very easy way. Just store the original HTML in a variable.

Comment: What? Yes, of course we can invent a million and one ways to cache values, or even entire DOM trees. And that's a rather different thing entirely that you are more than welcome to write your own answer for.

Comment: @connexo yes, though in my real-life case, I am making a change to the original HTML in its lowercased format before returning it to the UI (replacing all instances of a certain word with ```<mark>certain word</mark>``` in order to highlight those words on my page). So if I store the original HTML and then call it back, won't it return as the original HTML without my added change?

Comment: This is now a completely different question: highlighting words means you're putting them in markup, which means you can leave the text itself entirely along, and simply use CSS for that markup. Specify the `text-transform` CSS property, and we don't need to do any text replacement whatsoever.

Comment: @KatieReynolds the new answer addresses what you _actually_ wanted to do. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67249759/740553

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the first letter of the text by converting that letter to `toUpperCase()`:

```
someText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + someText.substring(1)
```

The first console shows the result from `toLowerCase()`. And the second console simulates the primary state of the text based on `toLowerCase()` above.

```js
let someText = document.querySelector(".wrapper p").innerHTML.toLowerCase();
console.log(someText);
console.log(someText.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + someText.substring(1));
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A great idea! However I think it'll be trickier to implement correctly in my real-life code, as I have some unorthodox sentences / list items / code snippets in which I don't want to capitalize the first letter each time. I will try anyway and see if it causes too many inconsistencies in my code, but I think I will just end up trying to learn more about RegExp as another commenter suggested. I haven't used it before but it seems like it will be helpful to me in many situations!